# Stopping Distance (frictionless)

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

Assuming I have a body travelling in space at a rate of $1000~\text{m/s}$. Let's also assume my maximum deceleration speed is $10~\text{m/s}^2$. How can I calculate the minimum stopping distance of the body?

All the formulas I can find seem to require either time or distance, but not one or the other.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braking_distance

Comment: v^2-u^2=-2as, v should be 0 as the object has to be stopped, and a is negative. Hence, s = u^2/2a. Which is 50,000m or 50km.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the speed is $1000 m/s$ and the deceleration is $10 m/s^2$, it will take $100 s$ to stop.  The average speed in that time is $500 m/s$, so the distance traveled is

$$500m/s*100s = 5*10^4m$$

Working through the same logic with an initial speed $v$ and a deceleration $a$, the final distance $d$ traveled before stopping is

$$d = v_{avg}*t = (v/2)*(v/a) = \frac{v^2}{2a}$$

This formula becomes more interesting when you learn a bit more physics because it's simple example of the [work-energy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)).

Answer (score 2):

The formula you want is

$$v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2a(x_f - x_i)$$

It's one of the basic kinematic formulas taught in high school (or even middle school) physics classes.

Comment: @David Well, I think that's a new record.  You beat me by three seconds.

Comment: Thanks, it's been a few years since I've done this math. Don't use something for almost a decade and you start to get rusty.

Comment: @Mark: well I haven't really been paying attention to the timing, but yeah, that is pretty close. Now you've got me wondering about the distribution of time differences between consecutive answers posted to the same question ;-)

Comment: @David: that's interesting, I'd love to see data on it! Is it possible to get high resolution time data for answer posting? We could plot the intervals on a histogram and make a meta thread.

Comment: @Colin: The [Stack Exchange API](http://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) provides posting times down to the second. You probably couldn't get better resolution than that (since I suspect it isn't stored in the database to any higher precision), but I think that should be enough since most of these time intervals are measured in hundreds or thousands of seconds.

Comment: @David: Awesome! Thank you for pointing me to that.

Answer (score 1):

Another equation of motion problem,very easy.

$$v^2 = u^2 + 2.a.s$$ where $$v = \textbf{final velocity} $$ , $$u = \textbf{initial velocity}$$ , $$a=\textbf{ acceleration or in this case negative acceleration}$$ , $$s = displacement$$ . This equation is time independent. Now, to find $s$ , put the values: $$s = \frac{-1000^2}{2.(-10)} \implies s = 50000~\text{m}$$ . Simple,right?

Comment: Ok, this is similar to @DavidZ but rarely do such easy questions come to be answered by a novice like me!

Answer (score 0):

Double integrate the acceleration with respect to time.  This first integral will give you the velocity graph based on the acceleration.  With the first integral, add a constant and find the constant by equating the first indefinite integral to the initial velocity at t=0.  This initial value will correct the deceleration for motion at time t=0.  The constant will allow for the second integration.  Now find at what time the first integral will equal 0 (the time when velocity equals 0). Integrate a second time with respect to time and substitute in the time figure of 0 and the final time and solve.  This will give you the full distance to stop.

integrate(a) dt = at + c; integrate(at + c) dt = ((at^2)/(2)) + ct; Sub in final time and solve, then sub in initial time (0) and subtract initial from final.

Answer (score 0):

- When brakes are applied to a moving vehicle, the distance it travels before stopping is called the **stopping distance**.
- It is an important factor for road safety and depends on the initial velocity ($v_0$) and the braking capacity, or the deceleration, $–a$ that is caused by the braking.
- Let the distance travelled by the vehicle before it stops be $d_s$. Then, using equation of motion $v^2 = {v_{o}}^2 + 2 ax$, and noting that $v = 0$, we
  have the stopping distance
  $$d_s = \frac{{-v_{0}}^2}{2a} $$
- Thus, the stopping distance is proportional to the square of the initial velocity. Substituting ${v_{o}}^2 = 1000~\text{m/s}$ and $a = -10~\text{m/s}^2$ in the above expression, we get $d_s = 50000~\text{m}$.